# Undefined refrence in a linked library

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Found [this](https://gist.github.com/bozdag/9909679) link to a c script that claims to take a screenshot of the running machine, so I copied it and installed all that libraries needed for compiling this file

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706512/cant-access-cairo-h)you can find info on how to to install the cairo lib

I am using gcc to compile the script and I tried compiling using the following commands

```
gcc -I/usr/include/cairo -lcairo -lX11 pic.c
gcc -I/usr/include/cairo -lX11 pic.c
gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/cairo -lm -lX11 pic.c
```

This is what i get when compiling

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccOh9u2g.o: in function `main':
pic.c:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
/usr/bin/ld: pic.c:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `cairo_xlib_surface_create'
/usr/bin/ld: pic.c:(.text+0x175): undefined reference to `cairo_surface_write_to_png'
/usr/bin/ld: pic.c:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `cairo_surface_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

this is what i am using

```
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "C script"

Comment: You try to compile and link the same file 3 times. Only one should be sufficient (the one with `-lcairo` and `-lX11` *after* the c file

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the libraries after the source files, so that the compiler knows where to look for the dependencies. In other words, the linker will search the libraries placed after the source file, for the functions called from the source file.

Something like

```
gcc -I/usr/include/cairo pic.c -lcairo -lX11
gcc -I/usr/include/cairo helloworld.c -lX11 
gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/cairo helloworld.c -lm -lX11
```

should do the job.

Comment: i tried it and i keep getting the same error